# Hook for rainbow-delimiters doesn't work

Tags: hooks

I use the following to setup rainbow-delimiters.

```
(use-package rainbow-delimiters
  :hook (prog-mode . rainbow-delimiters-mode))
```

When open a clojure file, the rainbow-delimiters-mode is not enabled.  I add some print messages to the rainbow-delimiters-mode function,

```
(define-minor-mode rainbow-delimiters-mode
  "Highlight nested parentheses, brackets, and braces according to their depth."
  nil "" nil ; No modeline lighter - it's already obvious when the mode is on.
  (font-lock-remove-keywords nil rainbow-delimiters--font-lock-keywords)
  (message "**** WIERD A")
  (when rainbow-delimiters-mode
    (message "**** WIERD B")
    (font-lock-add-keywords nil rainbow-delimiters--font-lock-keywords 'append)
    (set (make-local-variable 'jit-lock-contextually) t)
    (when (or (bound-and-true-p syntax-begin-function)
              (bound-and-true-p font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function))
      ;; We're going to modify `syntax-begin-function', so flush the cache to
      ;; avoid getting cached values that used the old value.
      (syntax-ppss-flush-cache 0))
    ;; `syntax-begin-function' may break the assumption we rely on that
    ;; `syntax-ppss' is exactly equivalent to `parse-partial-sexp' from
    ;; `point-min'. Just don't use it, the performance hit should be negligible.
    (when (boundp 'syntax-begin-function)
      (set (make-local-variable 'syntax-begin-function) nil))
    ;; Obsolete equivalent of `syntax-begin-function'.
    (when (boundp 'font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function)
      (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function) nil)))
  (when font-lock-mode
    (if (fboundp 'font-lock-flush)
        (font-lock-flush)
      (with-no-warnings (font-lock-fontify-buffer)))))
```

When opening a new clojure file, it will print out:

```
**** WIERD A
**** WIERD B
**** WIERD A
**** WIERD B
**** WIERD A
```

Comment: It is because of conflict with parinfer mode pretty-paren extension.

Comment: What's the question? If you want to report a bug, please report it to the library maintainer.